# Passing incompatible pointer types to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, types, incomplete-type

I am learning how to use functions passing through pointers.

I have a function that chops a double `d` into two parts, the `whole_part` and the `fraction_part`. So “425.25” would be chopped into “425” and “.25”.

I'm getting errors related to passing through pointer types. I'm not sure where problems like this arise. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void chop(double, long *, double *);

int main(void)
{
    double d;
    long * whole_part;
    double * fraction_part;

    printf("enter a double ");
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    // Call the function
    chop(d, &whole_part, &fraction_part);

    printf("%.10lf chopped is %ln and %.10lf", d, whole_part, fraction_part);

    return 0;
}


void chop(double d, long *whole_part, double *fraction_part)
{
    *whole_part = (int)d;
    *fraction_part = d - (double)whole_part;

}
```

Comment: "*I'm getting errors*". It would make sense to show the exact and complete errors. Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74355916/edit) the post with that info.

Comment: Akiyuu, `long * whole_part;` makes more sense as `long whole_part;`

Comment: Akiyuu, What do you think `"%ln"` is supposed to do?

Comment: `(double)whole_part` should be `(double)*whole_part`

Comment: Your error messages don't match the code you posted. The first error says `chop(&d` but the code is `chop(d`

Comment: Please post the errors as text and not as an image -  [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Initial problems:

`long` whole_part and `double` fraction_part should not be initialized in main as their variable pointers.

The function `chop()` should call the pointer to `whole_part` when attempting to use it to determine `fraction_part`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void chop(double, long *, double *);

int main(void)
{
    double d;
    long whole_part;
    double fraction_part;

    printf("enter a double ");
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    // Call the function
    chop(d, &whole_part, &fraction_part);

    printf("%.10lg chopped is %li and %.10lg\n", d, whole_part, fraction_part);

    return 0;
}


void chop(double d, long *whole_part, double *fraction_part)
{
    *whole_part = (int)d;
    
    *fraction_part = d - (double)*whole_part;

}
```